# OSM: Open Topo Map doesn't work signed .apk

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

This is an exceptionally strange issue I found with using open topo map in my android app. As soon as the android app is signed the open topo map stops loading tiles from:

> https://a.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

All the other tilelayers work fine (openstreet, mapbox).

Code:

```
let defaultCoordinates = { "lat": 52.370216, "lng": 4.895168 };
L.map('drawmap', {
      attributionControl: true,
      renderer: L.svg(),
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 20,
      zoomControl: true,
      layers: [L.tileLayer("https://a.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]
      }).setView([defaultCoordinates.lat, defaultCoordinates.lng], 13);
```

Comment: If you use Cordova, what is your white list?

Comment: @ghybs. thats it, forgot the whitelist... thanks!